# Add more than one chosen with same data list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have two chosen which has same data list. One chosen works fine while other one not displaying data as in the image. Thay are in same page but display on different div pop outs.

[image]

HTML CODE :
FIRST ONE

```
<select style="width: 100%;" id="vehicleGroups"
                                class="chosen-selectGroup" maxwidth="70px"></select>
```

SECOND:

```
<select  style="width: 100%;" id="vehicleGroupsOptions"
                                                class="chosen-selectGroup" maxwidth="70px"></select>
```

jquery

```
  function LoadVehicleGroupList(){
        $.post('functions.php',{'groupList':1},function(data){
            var groupList=JSON.parse(data);

            PopulateGroupList(groupList);
            $('.chosen-selectGroup').chosen({search_contains:true});
        });
    }

function PopulateGroupList(groupList){

    var listSize=groupList.length;
    var elements='';
    elements +='<option value="all">All</option>';
    for(var i=0;i<listSize; i++){
        var group=groupList[i];
        var groupName= group['Name'];
        var GroupID = group['GroupID'];
        elements +='<option value="'+GroupID+'">'+groupName+'</option>';
    }
    $('#vehicleGroups').html(elements);
    $('#vehicleGroupsOptions').html(elements);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated to solve this issue.

Comment: could you provide a fiddle , recreating your issue.

Comment: Please try   $("#chosen_id").trigger("chosen:updated"); after data is assigned to chosen..

Comment: @PrakashThete Thank for your support. I fixed this issue. I will update answer bit later.